# Vaadin Page.getCurrent().reload() logining out

Tags: vaadin, reload, vaadin7

I'm using `Page.getCurrent().reload()` with `@Push` anotation, it truely reloads the page, but it seems that it killing the vaadin session or something because it asking user to relogin after that.
Please suggest me something, fighting third day with this...

Answer (score 3):

Vaadin 7 does not preserve the application state on a page reload.
For this, you need to add the `@PreserveOnRefresh`on your main UI class.

```
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class PreserveStateUI extends UI {
    ...
}
```

[Wiki entry about state preservation](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+an+application+that+preserves+state+on+refresh)

Comment: In couple with @Push and reload() or just that anotation at all ? Sorry, I'm a new one to Vaadin

Comment: If you need Push, then add both